# How do I debug a arm9 2.4.19 linux hang?

Tags: linux, embedded, debugging, arm

I'm trying to debug this arm9 ... it's running some variation of Linux 2.4.19.

When I load a pci driver, the arm9 just hangs and reboots.

I've tried to enable to kernel hacking options in the menuconfig, but I don't see any error messages at all.  Just a hang, and a reboot.  That's all.

What else could I try?  I've never done this type of debugging before..

Answer (score 1):

There are some interesting tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762253/current-linux-kernel-debugging-techniques) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029639/debugging-an-operating-system).

I would also recommend taking a look at [this presentation](http://www.mulix.org/lectures/kernel_oopsing/kernel_oopsing.pdf) on kernel oopsing.